# Generic jquery structuration question

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

please take a look of this:

```
$(function () {

    $("#add").click(function() {

       val = $('#add_lang').val();
       val1 = $('#add_lang_level').val();

       listitem_html = '<li>';
       listitem_html += val + ' <strong>('+ val1 + '/100)</strong>';
       $.ajax({ url: 'addremovelang.php', data: {addname: val,addlevel: val1}, type: 'post', success: function(output) { alert(output); }});
       listitem_html += '<a href="#" class="remove_lang">Remove</a>'
       listitem_html += '</li>';

        $('#langs').append(listitem_html);

    });

    $('.remove_lang').live('click', function(e) {

       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).parent().remove();
       $.ajax({ url: 'addremovelang.php', data: {delname: val}, type: 'post', success: function(output) { alert(output); }});

    });


});
```

This simple jquery script adds strings to a html list when the user hits the button with the id add. Also, it puts a remove link to each line, so when the user hits remove it triggers the function remove_lang and the string is deleted.

When the users add a string, this text comes from a text field, and i stored it on the variable *val* (as you can see on the 5 line of the code). Then i call a php script via Ajax to add this info to my mysql database.

But, when the user remove the string, i dont know how to know what string was removed, i mean, the name of this one, that i need to send to my php script in order to remove it from the database.

Take a look of this version of my code without the ajax call: http://jsfiddle.net/wnFsE/

Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click remove you can do something like this:

```
    val = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
```

That will get the value from hidden input you added:

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wnFsE/6/)

Comment: what if i dont add the hidden parammeter? i will like to not add it. Any other way to retrive the language? here is a more explained code: http://jsfiddle.net/xw83U/

Comment: From your demo, to change it the least you could use: `val = $(this).parent('li').text().replace('Remove', '').replace(/\(+(.*)\)+/g, "");` that will get the text from the `<li>` you created, remove the `Remove` link, then uses regex to remove the `(blah)` brackets. This probably isn't best, but will work: http://jsfiddle.net/xw83U/1/ alternatively wrap the language and get it that way, see http://jsfiddle.net/xw83U/2/ - That is if you only want to language, if you wanted the level as well, it would take a little more to get?

Comment: No problem at all - glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about the string as instead a group of elements:

```
 var li = $('<li/>');
 var strong = $('<strong/>', { text: '(' + val1 + '/100)' });
 var link = $('<a/>');

 link.click(function()
 {
     // Insert code here for the link click
 });

 li.append(strong).append(link);

 $('#langs').append(li)
```

There are other patterns that would work too, like:

```
$(listitem_html').find('a').click(function()
{
     // Insert code here for the link click
});
```

Just get a reference to the element, and then attach the click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

An Object Oriented Programming approach would help keep the actions very organized. You basically store the actions for each given language in an object, modifying the action for that language whenever it's removed or added.

[Here's a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/4XS2h/1/) that will print that "storage" object out to the console every time you add or remove a language so that you can clearly see what's going on.

And here's just the JS code (you'll notice that I barely changed a thing):

```
languageActions = {}

$(function () {

    $("#add").click(function() {

       val = $('#add_lang').val();

       listitem_html = '<li>';
       listitem_html += val;
       listitem_html += '<input type="hidden" name="languages[]" value="' + val + '" /> ';
       listitem_html += '<a href="#" class="remove_lang">Remove</a>'
       listitem_html += '</li>';

       $('#langs').append(listitem_html);

       //now add it to our object
       languageActions[val] = 'add';

       console.log(languageActions);

    });

    $('.remove_lang').live('click', function(e) {

       e.preventDefault();
       val = $(this).prev().val();
       $(this).parent().remove();

       //now change it's value in languageActions
       languageActions[val] = 'remove';

       console.log(languageActions);

    });


});
```

The only other thing I'll point out is that you don't really need that hidden input element since you're doing this via AJAX rather than a standard form submit. Instead, you could just do `<li><span>Spanish</span><a class="remove_lang">Remove</a></li>` for your HTML and then the click event on .remove_lang would do `$(this).prev().text()` rather than `$(this).prev().val()`. Not a huge deal, but you're HTML will be a little cleaner.

Comment: Hello! i tested your solution but the val variable on the remove function is empty, any idea?

Comment: Here is a version with your modifications, it maybe let you see the problem http://jsfiddle.net/xw83U/

Comment: @DomingoSL - the val variable isn't empty. Did you try the fiddle I posted? It works perfectly for me.

Comment: in my fiddle (the last one with yours mods) is empty, there is something strange

Comment: Are you referring to the fiddle you posted a few comments up -  jsfiddle.net/xw83U ? Because that version does not have my modifications at all.

Answer (score -2):

I guess that would be a simple:

```
$i = 1;

while(xxx){
    //get the list with a different value for each element
    echo '<div id="add_' . $i . '>$whatever</div>';
    $i++;
}
```